# Simple "Random Number Guessing Game" / IF ELSE in C not working

Tags: c, if-statement, random

I have just started my Intro to Programming class (so please bear with me) and I am a bit stuck on one of the first assignments.

I am supposed to code a number guessing game to store a random number between 1 & 10 into a variable, prompt the user for a number, & notify if user guessed the same number or not.

I have been messing with it for some time now, and the code has changed quite a bit from what I started with. Currently, the program is saying "Congrats, you're a winner" no matter what I guess...

If anyone could just point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong, that would be great.

THE CODE HAS BEEN EDITED SINCE THE ORIGINAL POSTING OF QUESTION

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    //Declare Variables 
    int RandomNum;
    int UserGuess;

    //Initialize Variables
    RandomNum=0;
    srand ( (unsigned)time ( NULL ) );
    char UserInput = 'a';
    int a = UserInput;

    //Generate RandomNum
    RandomNum = (rand() % 10)+1;

    //Prompt User for UserInput
    printf("Guess the random number!\n");
    printf("Enter your guess now!\n");
    scanf("%d", &UserInput);

    //Determine Outcome
    if (UserInput == RandomNum) 
        printf("You're a WINNER!\n");
    else
        printf("Incorrect! The number was %d\n", RandomNum);

    //Stay Open
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: This `UserGuess=atoi("UserInput");` is just bad, and needs to be removed. This `scanf("%d", &UserInput);` tries to read an `int` into a `char`, which is not good news either.

Comment: You're still trying to stuff an `int` into a `char`. Change `char UserInput = 'a'; int a = UserInput;` to `int Userinput = 0;`. You don't use `a` for anything, so just leave it out of there. Remove `UserGuess`, too, since you don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of `UserInput`, remove `UserGuess` and the spurious call to `atoi()`, and it'll work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

//Declare Variables
    int RandomNum;
    int UserInput;      //  Changed to int

//Initialize Variables
    RandomNum = 0;
    UserInput = 0;      // Changed initialization
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

//Generate RandomNum
    RandomNum = (rand() % 10) + 1;

//Prompt User for UserInput
    printf("Guess the random number!\n");
    printf("Enter your guess now!\n");
    scanf("%d", &UserInput);

//Determine Outcome
    if (UserInput == RandomNum)
        printf("You're a WINNER!\n");

    else
        printf("Incorrect! The number was %d\n", RandomNum);

//Stay Open
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I swear I tried this earlier, I must have had something wrong lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Change this line -

```
if (UserGuess = RandomNum)
```

to this -

```
if (UserInput == RandomNum)
```

The first one **assigns** the user input stored in `RandomNum` into `UserGuess`, which is then converted to either true or false implicitly, and then the truth value of the `if` condition is checked by the compiler. I am assuming that you are entering non-zero value as your program input. If this is the case, then C will consider it as true. In fact, any non-zero value (whether positive, negative or fractional) is considered to be true by C.

The second expression checks for equality of two variables, rather than assigning one to another. So, you will get the desired behavior.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. D: Alas, I still have an issue. I'll enter "2", and still get the message "Incorrect, the number was 2"

Comment: @AllisonMcKillop: That's because you are storing the user input into the `UserInput` variable, where in the `if`, you are checking against the `UserGuess` variable. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I made the change you recommended but I am still having the same problem getting the "else" or incorrect message everytime, even when it says the random number was 2 and I typed in 2.

Comment: @AllisonMcKillop: That's because you are taking `2` as a character input, whose ASCII value is getting stored in the `UserInput` variable, which is equal to 50. Change `%c` to `%d` in the `scanf`, and you are good.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my code in my original post to reflect what (I think) you are saying. Now I am getting "Incorrect, the number was 0" every time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` is incorrect. `==` is equality, `=` is assignment.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. D: Alas, I still have an issue. I'll enter "2", and still get the message "Incorrect, the number was 2"

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `=` with `==`

`if (UserGuess = RandomNum)` will not give the boolean result which you want to check that whether the guess is equal to random no generated..

Use

```
if (UserGuess == RandomNum)
```

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that, and still have an issue. I'm getting the "else" or incorrect response even if I guess the correct number.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `atoi()` function takes an integer argument ?
because `atoi()` function is used to convert string to integer.

Read [this article](http://www.codingunit.com/c-reference-stdlib-h-function-atoi-convert-a-string-to-an-integer).

Comment: I think you are right. I used the following "char c = 'a'; // narrowing on C
int a = c;" as a guide. I will update my current code once i test it better and whatnot

Comment: See the updated code; it works, but when I take out "int UserGuess" every random number is 0. Why would that happen since it is an unused variable? Also, 'a' is an unused variable. I get warnings for "int format, different type, arg" and "control reaches end of a non-void function" I have no idea what those mean